# How to get the first element of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, linq-to-objects, html-lists

Is there a better way getting the first element of IEnumerable type of this:

```
foreach (Image image in imgList)
{
     picture.Width = (short)image.Columns;
     picture.Height = (short)image.Rows;
     break;
}
```

This is the exact declaration of the type:

```
public class ImageList : IEnumerable, IDisposable
```

Comment: Why you don't use generic `IEnumerable<T>` so `ImageList` could derive from `IEnumerable<Image>`?

Comment: @Arnis: because ImageLIst defien in ImageMagick.net library... :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
var firstImage = imgList.Cast<Image>().First();
```

Comment: @Mark, is Cast required.. cant we just use "var firstImage = ImgList.First()"  ??

Comment: @Ramesh: `Cast` is required in this case as `First` is implemented for `IEnumerable<T>` but `ImageList` only implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Ramesh Vel, you can't use imgList.First() as it's not a generic IEnumerable<T> before casting it.

Comment: @Brian, @jonC, sorry guys i wasnt aware of that "ImageList only implements IEnumerable" :(

Answer (score 10):

If you can't use LINQ you could also get the enumerator directly by `imgList.GetEnumerator()`
And then do a `.MoveNext()` to move to the first element.
`.Current` will then give you the first element.

Answer (score 6):

The extension `.First()` will grab the first item in an enumerable. If the collection is empty, it will throw an exception. `.FirstOrDefault()` will return a default value for an empty collection (null for reference types). Choose your weapon wisely!

Answer (score 0):

Might be slightly irrelevant to your current situation, but there is also a `.Single()` and a `.SingleOrDefault()` which returns the first element and throws an exception if there isn't exactly one element in the collection (`.Single()`) or if there are more than one element in the collection (`.SingleOrDefault()`).

These can be very useful if you have logic that depends on only having a single (or zero) objects in your list. Although I suspect they are not what you wanted here.

Comment: Actually I know Linq very well, but the `IEnumerable` was confusing since regularly work with `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I changed my datasource from a bindingsource to an entity framework query.

```
var query = dataSource as IQueryable;
var value = query.Where("prop = @0", value).Cast<object>().SingleOrDefault();
```

With entity framework this throw an exception `Unable to cast the type 'customer' to type 'object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

The class where my code was did not have a reference to the lib with the model so `...Cast<customer>` was not possible.

Anyway I used this approach

```
var query = dataSource as IQueryable;
var targetType = query.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
var value = query.Where("prop = @0", value).SingleOrDefault(targetType);
```

in conjunction with an IEnumerable extension which uses reflection

```
    public static object SingleOrDefault(this IEnumerable enumerable, Type type)
    {
        var method = singleOrDefaultMethod.Value.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { type });
        return method.Invoke(null, new[] { enumerable });
    }

    private static Lazy<MethodInfo> singleOrDefaultMethod 
         = new Lazy<MethodInfo>(() =>
             typeof(Extensions).GetMethod(
                 "SingleOrDefault", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic));

    private static T SingleOrDefault<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

feel free to implement caching per type to improve performance.